# Surface Deform modifier: MB-Lab subdvision modifier causes a render ERROR

Tags: surface-deform

I'm using a Surface Deform modifier on two meshes (clothing) deformed by a character mesh, as an efficient way to animate (applied) cloth.  If I then pose the Armature (moves the clothing mesh),  I see proper results in the 3D View, but a rendering throws the following error in the Console and the mesh is rendered in its original position.

[image]

```
ERROR (bke.modifier): C:\Users\blender\git\blender-v320\blender.git\source\blender\blenkernel\intern\modifier.c:456 BKE_modifier_set_error: Object: "Basic Wear Briefs.005", Modifier: "SurfaceDeform", Target polygons changed from 68296 to 273184
```

I attach the example blend file.  [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by a known phenomenon (not sure if an issue to fix or document) related to target meshes generate more mesh detail (e.g., Subdivision modifier).  So I am documenting this here, and commented on [T85566](https://developer.blender.org/T85566) and submitted to github.com MB-Lab issues.

When you create a character with MB-Lab add-on, it adds a Subdivision modifier with Levels of Viewport=1 and Render=2.

On the auxiliary mesh ("pants" in my example), if you then use a Surface Deform modifier to have the pants follow the deformation of the character mesh,  It looks fine in viewport but give the error I show in my Question above.

[T85566](https://developer.blender.org/T85566) suggests that you dup the char mesh, "remove any generative modifiers", and use that as the SD target.  yikes! file size!  Perhaps one could decimate to mesh copy to reduce the resulting file size.

What I did was just to change Subdivision modifier Render from 2 to 1, and see if I can live with any Render imperfections.

Comment: One convenient solution is to have a non-rendering surface deform target and then a geometry nodes object that instances that target, which you can follow up with as many subdivision levels as you'd like.  This shouldn't increase file size by more than a few bytes, because the geometry is instanced rather than straight up duplicated, and should be more forgiving performance-wise as well.

Comment: @Nathan -- I will try this when I get a chance.  Mucho thanko!